# HTML attribute comparison

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

How would you code a if conditional check in dojo?

```
if(!dojo.query("#idOfHhtmlField").attr("disabled") == true)
    { 
      //do something
    }
```

Here I am trying to compare if `#idOfHhtmlField`'s disabled attribute is set to true or not, but it doesnt seem to be working for me.

Comment: If you want to test the value in JavaScript, without causing type coercion, you need to use `===` triple equals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested this html in dojo,[here](http://jsfiddle.net/JnREG/):

```
<button id="test0" disabled>button0</button>
<button id="test1" disabled="disabled">button1</button>
<button id="test2" disabled="false">button2</button>
<div id="test3" disabled>div0</div>
<div id="test4" disabled="disabled">div1</div>
<div id="test5" disabled="false">div2</div>
```

since you can set div's disabled in ie8, so it returns all true.
but in chrome only the buttons return true.
you should check if #idOfHhtmlField is a form element .

## update

i suggest you detect disabled  this way,because browsers do not need its value:

```
if(dojo.hasAttr("id",'disabled')){
        //alert(123)
}
```

i know little about dojo , because dojo.query().attr() returns an object,it is weired!
and [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/hasAttr.html#dojo-hasattr) is the official guide.

Comment: Hi Simon, my browser is IE8 and this input field is of type Dojo type.

Comment: Simon, the second approach you suggested is throwing this error: 'getAttributeNode' is null or not an object

Comment: Simon, for some reason dojo.hasAttr doesnt work for disabled attribute. This has been pointed here <a href="http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/8991">Link</a>. dojo.attr(node, "disabled") works.

Comment: really?but my test case shows that hasAttr works well in ie8 and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!dojo.query("#idOfHhtmlField").disabled) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Delan, This one didnt work either. My flow is still getting inside the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Is `idOfHhtmlField` a DOM element (div, span, input etc)? or is it a dijit widget?

If it is a DOM node, you might want to use:

```
var field = dojo.byId('idOfHtmlField');
console.log(field.disabled);
```

If you are using a dijit widget of some type (either programmatic instantiation or declarative via dojoType or data-dojo-type), you will want to use:

```
var fieldWidget = dijit.byId('idOfHtmlField');
var isDisabled = fieldWidget.get('disabled');
console.log(isDisabled);
```